# run time error 9 subscript out of range when selecting workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to build a data entry form in Excel 2010 using VBA. During form initialization I am setting an object to refer to another worksheet so I can access it. This is what I have:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim master As Excel.Workbook
Dim masterworksheetFmn As Excel.Worksheet
Dim masterworksheetAdv As Excel.Worksheet
Dim masterworksheetTechs As Excel.Worksheet

Dim i As Integer

Set master = Excel.Workbooks("ServiceReturnsMaster.xlsm")
Set masterworksheetFmn = master.Worksheets("Foremen")
Set masterworksheetAdv = master.Worksheets("Advisors")
Set masterworksheetTechs = master.Worksheets("Techs")
```

When I run the macro, I get "Run Time error9: Subscript out of range". This occurs at this line:

```
Set master = Excel.Workbooks("ServiceReturnsMaster.xlsm")
```

HOWEVER, the error does not occur if I open the 2nd workbook before running the macro. I am assuming I have to activate the second workbook or something first or my reference is not written correctly. I can find lots of references to this run-time error, but none that directly address what I'm trying to do. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `Application.Workbooks` or just simply `Workbooks`

Comment: Do a find & replace and get rid of all `Excel.` strings. You are working within the application object by default. And yes, the workbook has to be open in the same application instance but it does not have to be the active workbook.

Comment: @ScottCraner - can you set a workbook object to an unopened workbook without opening it? I typically use `set master = workbooks.open(...
)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `Excel.Workbooks` you are referring to a *generic* `Workbooks` collection. If you want to access the `Workbooks` collection that is in your current application, then you need to use `Application.Workbooks`.

You can also use it without the `Application` qualifier as it's assumed you are working in the current application instance, so

```
Set master = Application.Workbooks("ServiceReturnsMaster.xlsm")
```

or

```
Set master = Workbooks("ServiceReturnsMaster.xlsm")
```

Should both work identically.

---

Alternatively, if your workbook isn't open at runtime, then you need to use the `Workbooks.Open()` method instead:

```
Set master = Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\to\ServiceReturnsMaster.xlsm")
```

Comment: @Macro Man What I want is to populate a combo box from another workbook without opening it, like this: 

'Populate Combo Boxes  
Do While masterworksheetFmn.Cells(i, 1).Value <> ""  
    ForemanBox.AddItem masterworksheetFmn.Cells(i, 1).Value  

    i = i + 1  
    
Loop  

Is there another method I should be using? I'd rather not have to open the other workbook.

Comment: You can't do that without opening the workbook in one way or another. Only option is to have formulas in your current workbook that reference the cells in the closed workbook - then use the result of those formulas. You _could_ in theory use ADO or something similar to query the workbook as a database but it would be ridiculous and complete overkill for what you're doing

Comment: @MacroMan is there any way to open the workbook so that it's minimized or at least in the background? Presently when I run the macro it opens the workbook on top of the form.